# Remove Users from a Teams Call Queue

Tags: powershell, office365, system-calls, microsoft-teams, audioqueueservices

I have a quick question and I wander if you can help. Does any of you know how to remove a user from a teams call queue using Powershell? For some reason I'm not able to do it through Admin Center.

On admin center I can see 4 items added to the queue meaning that my 4 users have been assigned but I have all options disabled and it doesn't let me to remove users. Has this every happened to any of you?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Thank you very much for the help
Tomas Gonzales

Answer (score 2):

if you have already created call queue setup. Please get the information of call queue and use set command to reset the user list.
getting information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-cscallqueue?view=skype-ps

Setting user list using set cmdlet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/set-CsCallQueue?view=skype-ps